# How to use the binary operator "%" with user input "readLine()"?

Tags: swift

I have been asked to write a code using If/Else statements. The code is supposed to ask the user to enter a number and then print "This number is even" if the number is even, and print "This number is odd" if the number is odd. To do this, I am using the binary operator "%" in order to find out whether the number imputed is even or odd. The problem is that I keep getting this error that says: "error: binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'Int' if  a %  2 ==  0". I do not know how to make the user input become an Int value instead of the default String so that the binary operator will work.

I have been suggested to try Type Casting, but nothing I do seems to be working.

```
print("This code will inform you whether the number you input is odd or even.")

print("Please enter a number of your choice.")

var a = readLine()

if  a %  2 ==  0 {
   print("This number is even.")
}
else  {
   print("This number is odd.")
}
```

I expect the user to be able to input a number and the computer to tell the user whether the number is odd or even.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**readLine()** returns an optional string. To unwrap optional there are couple of options in swift, I guess its three options there. One is force unwrapping, second is optional chaining and third is by **guard** statement. Here in the option below I have used optional chaining to unwrap optional string returned by **redLine()**. Try this:

```
if let typed = readLine() {
    if let num = Int(typed) {
        if  num %  2 ==  0 {
            print("This number is even.")
        }
        else  {
            print("This number is odd.")
         }
       }
     } else {
    print("Please enter a valid number")
}
```

Comment: You need to include a description of what was wrong and how your answer works. Just posting code isn't very helpful.

Comment: Got that, my bad